# Stack overflow with large fixed size array in Rust 0.13

Tags: arrays, stack-overflow, rust

I wish to verify with the Rust expert this simple Rust program (rustc 0.13.0-nightly on Linux x86-64 system):

```
/*
the runtime error is:
task '<main>' has overflowed its stack
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
*/

fn main() {
    let l = [0u, ..1_000_000u];
}
```

The compile process ends perfectly with no error but at runtime the program failed with the error shown in the code comment.

Is there a limit to the dimension of fixed size array in Rust or is this a bug somewhere in the compiler?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rust has a default stack size of 2MiB, you are just running out of stack space:

```
fn main() {
    println!("min_stack = {}", std::rt::min_stack());
}
```

To allocate the array of that size you have to allocate it on the heap using `box`:

```
fn main() {
    let l = box [0u, ..1_000_000u];
}
```