# How to allocate arrays on the heap in Rust 1.0?

Tags: arrays, rust, heap-memory

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637158/stack-overflow-with-large-fixed-size-array-in-rust-0-13) for this but related to Rust 0.13 and the syntax seems to have changed. From the current [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0-beta/book/pointers.html#cheat-sheet) I understood that creating an array on the heap would be something like this:

```
fn main() {
    const SIZE: usize = 1024 * 1024;
    Box::new([10.0; SIZE]);
}
```

But when I run this program I get the following error:

```
thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that the array is being passed to the `Box::new` function as an argument, which means it has to be created *first*, which means it has to be created *on the stack*.

You're asking the compiler to create *8 megabytes* of data on the stack: that's what's overflowing it.

The solution is to not use a fixed-size array at all, but a `Vec`.  The simplest way I can think of to make a `Vec` of 8 million `10.0` is this:

```
fn main() {
    const SIZE: usize = 1024 * 1024;
    let v = vec![10.0; SIZE];
}
```

Or, if for some reason you'd rather use iterators:

```
use std::iter::repeat;

fn main() {
    const SIZE: usize = 1024 * 1024;
    let v: Vec<_> = repeat(10.0).take(SIZE).collect();
}
```

This *should* only perform a single heap allocation.

Note that you can subsequently take a `Vec` and turn it into a `Box<[_]>` by using the [`into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) method.

See also:

- [Performance comparison of a Vec and a boxed slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33704592/155423)

Comment: Note that there is `box` syntax which is supposed to help with this but it is unstable now and I'm not sure if it supports direct heap placement of arrays yet.

Comment: You should be able to use `vec![10.0; 1024 * 1024]`.

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is very unsatisfying as sometimes we *do* want arrays allocated on the heap to preserve the size information at the type level. Johannes's answer can now be slightly improved using const generics. Instead of a macro we can use a function like:

```
fn vec_to_boxed_array<T: Copy, const N: usize>(val: T) -> Box<[T; N]> {
    let boxed_slice = vec![val; N].into_boxed_slice();

    let ptr = Box::into_raw(boxed_slice) as *mut [T; N];

    unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this too, and ended up first at [Creating a fixed-size array on heap in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25805174/creating-a-fixed-size-array-on-heap-in-rust/68122278#68122278) where you find the full answer.

The gist of the answer is this macro:

````
/// A macro similar to `vec![$elem; $size]` which returns a boxed array.
///
/// ```rustc
///     let _: Box<[u8; 1024]> = box_array![0; 1024];
/// ```
macro_rules! box_array {
    ($val:expr ; $len:expr) => {{
        // Use a generic function so that the pointer cast remains type-safe
        fn vec_to_boxed_array<T>(vec: Vec<T>) -> Box<[T; $len]> {
            let boxed_slice = vec.into_boxed_slice();

            let ptr = ::std::boxed::Box::into_raw(boxed_slice) as *mut [T; $len];

            unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr) }
        }

        vec_to_boxed_array(vec![$val; $len])
    }};
}
````

which I like most, as it simply gives you what the OP wanted:

An array, and it works with stable rust.