# How to set a Rust array length dynamically?

Tags: arrays, rust

I want to create array like this:

```
let arr = [0; length];
```

Where length is a `usize`. But I get this error

```
E0307
The length of an array is part of its type. For this reason, this length 
must be a compile-time constant.
```

Is it possible to create array with dynamic length? I want an array, not a `Vec`.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why do you not want to use a Vec?

Comment: Maybe you should describe which qualities of a `Vec` you think are lacking that an array satisfies.

Comment: Or maybe use `Slice`, it is similar to `Array` but size of a `Slice` does not have to be known at compile time.

Comment: I have some functions that accepts references to array, so i need array for it.

Comment: @DimaKudosh, are you sure they accept references to an array, not slices (e.g. `&[u32]`)? If they are in fact slices, then `Vec<T>` is freely convertible to `&[T]`, usually with just `&`: `let v: Vec<u32> = ...; let s: &[u32] = &v`. And if they do in fact accept references to an array, then how dynamically sized arrays would help you? Rust does not have type-level integers, so the size of the array would be necessarily constant in this case.

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev,I create trait for reading u16, u32 and etc from stream and try to implement it for File struct. But I don't want to implement many similar methods, and I try to create one function and call it in this methods with different parameters. Firstly I try to pass length of buffer to it and read this buffer from file and then convert, but it's impossible to create dynamic array. Then I try to create Vec, I convert to integer using transmute and it's panic because Vec hasn't fixed length. Then I pass array but it's impossible to convert [u8;2] to [u8].Maybe you know better solution?

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev,or better to make this function  using adding and shifts instead of transmute?

Comment: Of course you should not use transmutes for this. This is not portable. If you need to read binary numbers from a byte stream I suggest you to use [byteorder](https://crates.io/crates/byteorder) crate which does exactly that in a correct way.

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev, Thank you

Comment: I think you might be looking for [tinyvec](https://docs.rs/tinyvec/latest/tinyvec/)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> Is it possible to create array with dynamic length?

No. By definition, arrays have a length *defined at compile time*. A variable (because it can *vary*) is not known at compile time. The compiler would not know how much space to allocate on the stack to provide storage for the array.

You will need to use a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html):

```
let arr = vec![0; length];
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)

Comment: Is [`Vec::into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice) an option then? How does it compare to a plain Vec or an array?

Comment: @iago-lito does [What is the use of into_boxed_slice() methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39615666/155423) and [Performance comparison of a Vec and a boxed slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33704592/155423) answer your question?

Answer (score 16):

This should be possible after [variable length arrays (VLA)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html) are implemented.

Comment: I really do hope they implement this. I want to ditch C++ with Rust and I will only trust them if they choose not do same mistakes C++ did. C++ didnt implement designated initializers with random "reasons" VLAs are very similar. They are cornerstones of performance computing both because it helps prevent cache misses which is also very important helper of speculative execution optimizaion. C# developers did the right thing by introducing "stackalloc" and believe me it is really required for next-gen optimizations

Comment: What would be advantages of such dynamic arrays vs vec? They are on stack and not on heap, anything else? Vec layout is already as efficient as it may be on the heap, is that correct? For bigger size array stack won't work, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `HeapArray`. It's not that complicated if you read [`alloc`'s docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/alloc/):

```rust
use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};
pub struct HeapArray<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    len: usize,
}

impl<T> HeapArray<T> {
    pub fn new(len: usize) -> Self {
        let ptr = unsafe {
            let layout = Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(len, std::mem::size_of::<T>());
            alloc(layout) as *mut T
        };
        Self { ptr, len }
    }
    pub fn get(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        if idx < self.len {
            unsafe { Some(&*(self.ptr.add(idx))) }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    pub fn get_mut(&self, idx: usize) -> Option<&mut T> {
        if idx < self.len {
            unsafe { Some(&mut *(self.ptr.add(idx))) }
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len
    }
}


impl<T> Drop for HeapArray<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            dealloc(
                self.ptr as *mut u8,
                Layout::from_size_align_unchecked(self.len, std::mem::size_of::<T>()),
            )
        };
    }
}

impl<T> std::ops::Index<usize> for HeapArray<T> {
    type Output = T;
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        self.get(index).unwrap()
    }
}
impl<T> std::ops::IndexMut<usize> for HeapArray<T> {
    fn index_mut(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Self::Output {
        self.get_mut(index).unwrap()
    }
}
```

You may also add methods like `as_slice`, `get_unchecked`, etc.

Comment: size argument of `from_size_align_unchecked` is in bytes. So you have to multiply `self.len` to `std::mem::size_of::<T>()` to calculate total size.

Comment: How is this different from `Vec`? It does a heap allocation, just like `Vec` does.

Comment: This code is 100% memory unsafe and should not be used by anyone. `let ha = HeapArray::<String>::new(10); println!("{}", ha[7]);` causes a segfault. Working cases would result in memory leaks. "It's not that complicated" to write buggy code.