# How to extract a usize bytes and return them?

Tags: arrays, rust, type-conversion

I am trying to extract the bytes of a `usize` to retrieve them in a `u8` array but it seems impossible to initialize an array with a "runtime-known" size.

Here is my code:

```
use std::mem;
use std::mem::transmute;

fn encodeString(value: &str) {
    let length: usize = value.len(); // retrieval of the size
    let lengthSize: usize = mem::size_of_val(&length); // I am on 64-bit so it is 8

    let lengthBytes: [u8; lengthSize] = unsafe { transmute(lengthSize.to_be() }; // BAM. Does not want to compile because of the lengthSize
}

fn main() {
    encodeString("Coucou");
}
```

I tried to set the `lengthSize` variable as a constant using `const` instead of `let` but, as you will notice, I have the error that it is not "constant".

Because I did not succeed in doing what I wanted, I tried another way by using a `Vec` but... I have another error concerning its size and I did not find how I can force to use a `Vec` with only 8 entries of `u8`:

```
let lengthBytes: Vec<u8> = unsafe { transmute(length.to_be()) }; // BAM. 15:50 error: transmute called with differently sized types: usize (64 bits) to std::vec::Vec<u8> (192 bits) [E0512]
```

Maybe if I convert the `usize` to a string and then I convert it back to a `u8` array? But that seems to be... overkill.

==== My solution

So... I found another way by rotating the bits. Here is my code:

```
fn splitToVector(value: usize) -> Vec<u8> {

  println!("Value of the usize: {}", value);

  let length = mem::size_of_val(&value);
  println!("Usize coded on {} bytes", length);

  let mut splitted_value: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(length);

  for x in 1..length + 1 {
    let bitPack: u8 = value.rotate_left(8 * x as u32) as u8;
    println!("Content of the bitPack number {}: {}", x, bitPack);
    splitted_value.push(bitPack);
  }

  return splitted_value;    
}

fn main {
  let coucou_size: usize = "Coucou".len();

  let coucou_size_bytes = splitToVector(coucou_size);
  assert_eq!(coucou_size_bytes.capacity(), mem::size_of_val(&coucou_size));
  assert_eq!(String::from_utf8(coucou_size_bytes).unwrap().as_bytes(), coucou_size.to_string().as_bytes());
}
```

The function that splits the usize in bytes is splitToVector which returns a vector of u8 because it is impossible to define the length of an array at runtime (as defined in this post provided by Shepmaster: [How to set a Rust array length dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684261/how-to-set-a-rust-array-length-dynamically))

Comment: Rust style is `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`ByteOrder::write_u64`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/byteorder/trait.ByteOrder.html#tymethod.write_u64)?

Comment: It sounds like [usize#swap_bytes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.usize.html#method.swap_bytes) might be what you're doing?

Comment: @Shepmaster: To learn, I prefered a more natibe way than using an existing crate

Comment: @carols10cents: No, that is not what I wanted. I wanted to retrieve the bytes composing the usize of the string I passed.

Comment: I added my solution in the initial post if you wanna take a look :)