# What is the use of into_boxed_slice() methods?

Tags: types, rust, containers, slice, boxing

Looking at the methods available for `Vec<T>` I stumbled across

```
into_boxed_slice(self) -> Box<[T]>
```

`String` also has such a method (`into_boxed_str(self)`). The usefulness of having `Deref` for `Vec<T>`/`String` that allows them to be treated like a shared slice (`&[T]`) is obvious, but I don't see any use for an owned slice (`Box<[T]>`) except, perhaps, FFI. The Rust GitHub repo only uses `into_boxed_slice()` in a handful of cases.

Since methods for creating boxed slices are available in `std` and this container is listed on its main page, I thought that I might be missing something useful about it. What are cases where I should use an owned slice in favor of a `Vec<T>` or a `String`?

Comment: Not sure if it's *the* reason, but `Box<[T]>` and `Box<str>` have one less pointer-sized integer as they don't need a capacity — they can't be resized.

Comment: I thought about this, but it doesn't strike me as a reason enough to have a dedicated container either.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "dedicated container". It's just a combination of existing types - `Box` and `[T]` or `str`. It's not really that different from a `Box<Trait>`.

Comment: You're right, though it is listed in the main page of `std`, which gives it a feeling of some nobility :). That's what got me interested in it.

Comment: I'd guess it's probably just meant to be a cheap, safe way of getting the underlying heap pointer. Effectively an "into_inner" method. Probably provided in case somebody really wants to own the underlying buffer for reasons that weren't considered very strongly because it's trivial to implement.

Comment: Otherwise, to avoid intermediate allocations, you have to go through unsafe shenanigans like `Box::from_raw(&mut vec[..] as *mut [T])`, and then manually forget the Vec, which is just unpleasant. It's nicer to just provide a safe alternative.

Comment: I saw the implementation and it makes sense; I'd still like to know some practical use of owning the inner buffer, though (if there are other than FFI).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The big reason for using `into_boxed_slice()` is that a boxed slice takes up *only* as much memory as:

- The underlying data itself
- A `length` field that gives the total length of the data

When using a standard `Vec` it is possible, and common, for the `Vec` to obtain more memory than what it actually needs to avoid having to allocate more memory every time a new element is added. That space is essentially unused. You can find out how much extra memory is being used by comparing `Vec::len()` versus `Vec::capacity()`.

The main place that I have found the `into_boxed_slice()` function useful is in an in-memory file cache. I load the file into memory using a `Vec` for simplicity, but once the file is loaded, I no longer need to add or remove elements. So I convert it to a boxed slice using `into_boxed_slice()`. There would be other ways to achieve the same thing, but in this case the single function call is easier. I like the boxed slice type (as opposed to a `Vec`) because it clearly signals the intent that the cached file is not meant to modified.

Note: you can actually still use a `Vec` without the extra overhead by calling `Vec::shrink_to_fit()`, which will remove the extra allocated elements from the `Vec`.

Comment: If I can remember correctly, `into_boxed_slice()` calls `shrink_to_fit()` too. It's a valid answer; I was hoping to learn some hidden benefits, but there just might not be any. I'll accept it if nothing surprising comes up soon.

Comment: `shrink_to_fit` doesn't guarantee that length will equal capacity after it returns. The docs say it will shrink "as much as possible": https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit

`into_boxed_slice` internally does use `into_boxed_slice`, but also guarantees the returned slice will be of length `vec.len()`, so it goes beyond the guarantees  of `shrink_to_fit`

Answer (score 1):

I have an application where I have a `Vec` of tens of thousands of elements, each of which could be a `Vec` or a `Box<[T]>` so I save hundreds of thousands of bytes by  using `into_boxed_slice`.

Comment: I mean you save by not needing the `capacity` field in the `Vec` by having a slice `[T]`? Is that the reason?

Comment: @RequireKeys Yes, that's the reason. So 8 bytes per Vec (or String) is saved on a 64 bit architecture.