# Is it possible to define a constant value from the terminal?

Tags: arrays, rust, constants

In order to create an array in rust it needs to have a predefined size:

```
arr = [u32; 4];
```

If instead of 4 I use a variable, it gives an error, unless it is a constant defined for example as:

```
const SIZE: usize = 4;
```

The question: **is there a way to define the size of the array according to input from the terminal (command line arguments) when running the program?** 
My assumption is that the const has to be defined in compile time, so not using a const. Maybe using a slice this is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a Rust array length dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684261/how-to-set-a-rust-array-length-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must have a size known at compile time. If you want a dynamically sized array, try using a [Vec](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) instead, which can have an arbitrary size and can also be grown/shrunk as necessary.