# Is there a way to configure the value of a const variable in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am writing a rust library where I use [embedded-alloc](https://github.com/rust-embedded/embedded-alloc). I want the users of my library to be able to configure the size of the heap, which is a static array, according to their platform.

I tried something like this, which doesn't work:

```
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
extern crate alloc;

use cortex_m_rt::entry;
use embedded_alloc::LlffHeap as Heap;

#[global_allocator]
static HEAP: Heap = Heap::empty();

fn init<const N: usize>() {
     use core::mem::MaybeUninit;
     const HEAP_SIZE: usize = N;
     static mut HEAP_MEM: [MaybeUninit<u8>; HEAP_SIZE] = [MaybeUninit::uninit(); HEAP_SIZE];
     unsafe { HEAP.init(HEAP_MEM.as_ptr() as usize, HEAP_SIZE) }
}
```

```
// User code.
fn main() {
    init::<1024>();
}
```

```
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer item
 --> src/main.rs:2:31
  |
1 | fn init<const N: usize>() {
  |               - const parameter from outer item
2 |     const HEAP_SIZE: usize = N;
  |                               ^ use of generic parameter from outer item

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0401`.
error: could not compile `rust_const_generic` (bin "rust_const_generic") due to previous error
```

Is there any way to allow the users of my crate to configure the size of the internal static array?

Comment: I don't know rust at all, but can't you just pass in a number as a parameter? As in, they give you a number as one of the params, you give them an array of that size.

Comment: I want to configure the size of a static array. I don't want to return a new array to the user. So I cannot do what you say.

Comment: In that case, I am barely confident in saying that what you are trying to do is impossible. Let me link you to an answer that says something similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a Rust array length dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684261/how-to-set-a-rust-array-length-dynamically)

Comment: Alternatively, how about this one? -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28137604/10118965

Comment: A static value has to have a single type determined at compile time, and for a static array that would include the array length. Also consider what happens to the static array if the user of your library calls `init::<5>()` followed by `init::<10>()`? I don't think you can achieve your goals without some unsafe code. To show that code we need to understand what problem you are trying to solve and what are your constraints.

Comment: @user4815162342 I edited my question to provide more context.

Comment: @Koija Thanks for the clarification. Rust really wants to prevent you from doing that - the closest I could get is [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f843c6980a9f3c45163ada58cd35f79d) (using the technique adapted from [here](https://morestina.net/blog/1940/compile-time-checks-in-generic-functions-work-and-you-can-use-them-in-your-code)), but it's not mutable, so it might well end up in readonly segment.

Comment: An unrelated note: I consider `embedded-alloc`'s heap's `init()` taking a `usize` address instead of a pointer to be a design mistake. It enters a dark area of pointer provenance and pointer-to-int casts. Anyway, if you use `as_mut_ptr()` instead of `as_ptr()` you will be a tad safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making `init()` a *function*, you can make it a *macro*. Macros can declare `static` items with parameters they get.

In the library, have some not-API-exposed (but exposed to the macro) function that initializes the heap given a pointer to the static:

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
pub unsafe fn init_impl(start: *mut u8, size: usize) {
    HEAP.init(start as usize, size);
}

#[doc(hidden)]
pub use core::mem::MaybeUninit;

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! init {
    ( $size:expr $(,)? ) => {{
        const __MY_LIBRARY__HEAP_SIZE: usize = $size;
        static mut __MY_LIBRARY__HEAP_MEM: [$crate::MaybeUninit<u8>; __MY_LIBRARY__HEAP_SIZE] = [$crate::MaybeUninit::uninit(); __MY_LIBRARY__HEAP_SIZE];
        $crate::init_impl(__MY_LIBRARY__HEAP_MEM.as_mut_ptr().cast::<u8>(), __MY_LIBRARY__HEAP_SIZE);
    }};
}
```

Then in the user code:

```rust
fn main() {
    init!(1024);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting when compiling your sample ([E401](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0401.html)) is that inner items defined within an item do not inherit generic parameters. The function declaration itself is the outer item, while the declaration of the const is an inner item. Also note that in stable rust, const items can't accept generic parameters (although there is a [tracking item](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/113521) open for this, so it may be possible in future).

Unfortunately the same restriction also applies to `static` items:

```
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer item
 --> src/lib.rs:3:33
  |
1 | fn init<const ARRAY_SIZE: usize>() {
  |               ---------- const parameter from outer item
2 |     // You can use it to define the size of an array at compile time
3 |     static ary: [u8; 200] = [0; ARRAY_SIZE];
  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ use of generic parameter from outer item
```

The best you are going to be able to do is require your crate's caller to declare the heap themselves, and pass it to the functions of your crate that need it. For example:

```rust
use core::mem::MaybeUninit;

struct HeapMem<const HEAP_SIZE: usize> {
    data: [MaybeUninit<u8>; HEAP_SIZE]
}

impl <const HEAP_SIZE: usize> HeapMem<HEAP_SIZE> {
    const fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            data: [MaybeUninit::uninit(); HEAP_SIZE]
        }
    }
}

fn init_heap<const HEAP_SIZE: usize>(heap_mem: &HeapMem<HEAP_SIZE>) {
    // Use provided heap_mem to initialize your global allocator
    println!("Addr: {}, size: {}", heap_mem.data.as_ptr() as usize, HEAP_SIZE);
}

fn main() {

    static HEAPMEM: HeapMem<5> = HeapMem::new();

    init_heap(&HEAPMEM);

}
```

Comment: You may have linked the wrong issue. It links to "Tracking issue for HashMap::raw_entry".

Comment: How does this answer the question about using it in a `static` array?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oops, I should have read the question more closely. I've updated now, and also fixed the link you pointed out.

Comment: This is probably the best approach - just allow the caller to provide a static array (and give them a helper to do that), and pass it to `init`. Perhaps a bit less magical than what the OP was going for, but much easier to understand/debug than a macro-based solution.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, there are two ways you can do this, it's either you want to initialize random values for the array using the size passed by the user, or you can just make the array return default values for the specified length.

Look at the example below.

```
// generate random values for the 
// data type using the len passed 
// by the user 
fn set_array_values<const LEN:usize>() -> [f64; LEN] {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut arr = [0.;LEN];
    for item in arr.iter_mut() {
        *item = rng.gen::<f64>() * 100.;
    }
    arr
}

// use default values for the 
// specific type with the length passed by user
fn _set_array_val<const LEN:usize>() -> [f64; LEN]{
    let arr = [0.; LEN];
    arr
}

fn main(){
    let first_array:[f64; 5] = set_array_values();
    let second_array:[f64; 10] = set_array_values();
    println!("first value = {:?}", first_array);
    println!("second value = {:?}", second_array);
}
```

You can run this code on the Rust playground here

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f6c418d40b28ada94fa2ab5108cee4f8