# What's the best choice for non-resizable dynamic length arrays in Rust?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

I'm re-implementing a hashtable in Rust.  Eventually I'd like to make this distributed and have quorums, but for now it's a hashtable on a single system.

I want the size of the table to be passed in as an argument so the table should be dynamically sized.  I don't want the table to grow because that will mess with my hash function which works off a modulo operation.  I see a couple of options:

1. Arrays - cannot be dynamically sized
2. Vectors - can grow
3. Slices - can be dynamically sized & can't grow, but are just views onto `Vec`s and arrays, so I'll need a `Vec`/array anyways?

In C++, I could have just used a dynamically sized array.  What's the best choice here?

Comment: `vec![0; n].into_boxed_slice();`? https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3gp0tl/dynamic_fixed_sized_arrays/

Comment: btw, if you don't want vector to grow, why not to not grow it? I suppose your users don't have access to it. also, there's a possibility you'll reconsider this later, I'm really curious what that "not ever growable" vector inside a hashtable stores

Comment: I could make my own protections, but I thought it would be nice to use a collection that met my requirements if it existed.

Comment: What do you call "dynamically sized array" in C++ by the way?

Comment: https://crates.io/keywords/array offers several that appear to match your description, have you tried any?

Comment: @mcarton `auto array = new type[dimension]` for example

Comment: @Boiethios that's not idiomatic C++. People have been using RAII for a long time now, and there are no standard RAII wrappers for such arrays that are aware of the array size.

Comment: @mcarton I agree, but that is yet C++. Obviously, OP wrote about that, RAII or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A *boxed slice* is dynamically sized, the length cannot be changed once created, and it owns the contained data:

```
let the_vec: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3];
let the_boxed_slice: Box<[i32]> = the_vec.into_boxed_slice();
```

The types aren't required here, they are just present for pedagogical reasons.

---

However, it's dubious whether you will get any *performance* benefit. A `Vec` is three pointer sized values (data, size, capacity). A `Box<[T]>` is only two: data and size. The overhead of having the extra value is minuscule in most cases.

The main benefit is to be statically guaranteed that the size won't *change*; you won't statically know that it's a certain size. Such a guarantee *might* happen if [type-level numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423) ever happen.

See also:

- [Performance comparison of a Vec and a boxed slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33704592/155423)

Comment: There's a lot to be said for having the structure that is guaranteed not to change size. So much that it won't fit into the size of the margin here.