# How do I force Rust to allocate a big object on the heap without using a Vec?

Tags: rust

I have a large object

```
pub(crate) struct Grid {
    pub weights: [[[f32; GRID_SIZE]; GRID_SIZE]; GRID_SIZE],
    // ... other attributes
}
```

With a large grid size, it does not fit on the stack and causes a stack overflow. I tried to create a `Box`, but `Box::new(Grid { .. })` still overflows since Rust tries to create the entire object on the stack and copy it to the heap afterwards. How do I create some type of box or reference immediately for objects that don't fit on the stack?

I found [How to allocate arrays on the heap in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242770/how-to-allocate-arrays-on-the-heap-in-rust-1-0), but this works only for a array and not for an arbitrary struct. I assume there must be a good way to create a pointer directly without converting back and forth to a vector.

The `box Grid {}` syntax seems to not work either, Rust complains that that syntax is experimental.

Comment: As suggested, there's no such stable feature yet

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the effect with perhaps some `unsafe{}` memory manipulation?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a `Vec`? A `Vec` is not much more than a pointer to an array in heap memory (in fact, it's a pointer plus a length field).

Comment: Well, the object is not only an array